error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.js
Предыстория вопроса
Отличие в том, что у меня другой антивирус. Но мой антивирус уже предоставляет готовый .pem файл. Как-то его можно установить?

Помогла следующая последовательность команд:
$ openssl x509 -outform der -in root.pem -out certificate.crt

root.pem - файл, предоставленный антивирусом.
Опирался на англоязычный ответ. Далее - как в примере:
$ sudo openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.crt -out /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/antivirus.crt
$ sudo update-ca-certificates

